# Access CSS variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

Is there a way to access a css variable from javascript? Here my css variable declaration.

```css
:root {
  --color-font-general: #336699;
}
```

Comment: I am really curious as to why you don't want to re-declare that variable in javascript which is more efficient

Comment: @Dummy Then there would be two places in which the value needed to be maintained, making the code more fragile (i.e. not a DRY approach).

Comment: In my case, I don't know which CSS file it's using. The user decides the file, and each file has different values for this variable.

Comment: Also, if you have CSS variables that have different values depending on which active `@media` query defines them, you save yourself even more work and duplicate code.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Just the standard way:

1. Get the computed styles with [`getComputedStyle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle)
2. Use [`getPropertyValue`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) to get the value of the desired property

```js
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('--color-font-general');
```

Example:

```js
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body)
console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--bar') ) // #336699
console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--baz') ) // calc(2px*2)
```

```css
:root { --foo:#336699; --bar:var(--foo); --baz:calc(2px*2); }
```

Comment: Looks like it isn't working in IE 10, any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: @webkitfanz you do realize that css variables are not supported in IE, right?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without causing a reflow as getComputedStyle will do this?

Comment: Note that the value returned has the leading space, so you would get " #336699" instead of "#336699". This matters if you are trying to check the value (it may not match because of that leading space, so consider trimming it before checking).

Comment: @EricMutta I just experienced this. So annoying. Why would they return with a leading space in the string?

Comment: It should be `window.getComputedStyle` mate.

Comment: @Lilboat It doesn't matter; `window` is the global object.

Comment: None of these solutions is working for us.

Answer (score 63):

Use this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--color-font-general');
```

And you can change it like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-font-general', '#000');
```

[source](https://www.broken-links.com/2014/08/28/css-variables-updating-custom-properties-javascript/)

Comment: It actually would be `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-font-general', '#000');` if you wanted to change it.

Comment: whoops fixed. thanks!

Comment: You can also get it like that: `element.style.getPropertyValue()`

Comment: @Rudie `element.style.getPropertyValue()` will only work if the variable has been set on the inline style of the element (not through a CSS rule)