# How to access the :root's element in ReactJS to edit CSS variables?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working currently with ReactJS and I would access CSS element to edit the CSS variables inside my stylesheet.  I have seen some articles talking about  access CSS variable using getElementById. The difficulty is that my element doesn't have any ID - it is the :root  element on my stylesheet.

How to access it to handle my CSS variables?
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Simply add a css loader and use :root in your style sheet.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried to use document.:root on React but it doesn't works

Comment: `:root` == `html`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access CSS variable from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725725/access-css-variable-from-javascript)