# Unable to access a CSS property through javascript

Tags: javascript, css

#### CSS

```css
<style scoped>

  body  {
    --main-colour: "deep-purple"
  }
  
  :root {
    --main-colour: "deep-purple"  
  }
```

#### Javascript

```js
            colour() {
                console.log(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--main-colour'))
                console.log(getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--main-colour'))
                console.log(document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--main-colour'))
            }
```

#### Problem

After looking on [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36088890/8940624) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725782/8940624), it seems I should be able to access my CSS variable from within the javascript, but it's not being found...on some posts I've seen the getComputedStyle pointing at various different elements so I've tried all that I've seen, and also put the variable inside the body rather than the :root (the latter seeming to be the convention), but still not getting any joy.

```
<empty string>
<empty string>
```

Comment: Hm, the only reason I can think of is the `scoped` attribute of your `<style>` tag. Otherwise it works for me.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I did think it may be related but it seems I hadn't refreshed when I tried it before...oops