# How can i change css variable to scss color type?

Tags: css, sass

I add css variable to root because i want to change it dynamically by using JS

```
#root {
  --primary-color: #4c5b73;
}

$primary-color: var(--primary-color) !default;

.my-component {
 background-color: transparentize($primary-color, 0.85);
}
```

I want to use the Basic scss function `transparentize`
or `lighter`  or `darker`

***But i got this error***

```
Argument `$color` of `transparentize($color, $amount)` must be a color
```

How can i tell that this is a color type?

## Update

I should do this more earlier
https://codepen.io/colton123/pen/bGVbRjP

Comment: Try `:root {}` instead of `#root {}`. `#root` selects an element with the `id` equal to `root`. This will create a scoped block. Declaring CSS variables in this block will make it so that only code within the block can access the variable. If that doesn’t work, create an SCSS variable `$my-color: #fff:` above `:root {}` and set your CSS variable’s value equal to the SCSS variable.

Comment: @kahn Thanks! but it wasn't problem of nesting , i change #root => :root  but same error

Comment: You can try putting `$primary-color: #4c5b73;` at the top of your file and declare a CSS variable by doing `——primary-color: $primary-color;` *(excuse any errors, I’m not on a computer)*.

Comment: @Khan it will generate in css ```---primary-color: $primary-color``` it will not compile the code

Comment: @khan Yeap but in that way, can't change all color by change root color.  
Maybe i should give up making it a scss variable

Comment: Yes, you’re right. You need to interpolate it to get the value.

Comment: @khan I think a lot has changed since I first studied.i should try again after studying. and i will find proper way  thanks! i will search about interpolate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the alpha channel in regular CSS if you define the color using decimal RGB values instead of a hex code:

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: 76, 91, 7;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.my-component {
  background-color: rgba(var(--primary-color), 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-component">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works for me , but i want to collect more answer. Maybe there is a better way

Comment: This is a correct answer, but technically it isn't the answer to the question, as it states to do 'using js.'

Comment: @JoelHager The question does not ask how to do it in JavaScript, nor is it tagged with JavaScript. The linked code in the question also demonstrates that OP has no problems with changing the value of a CSS variable in JavaScript, and OP accepted my answer. So what's your point?

Comment: @JoelHager 
Because the other answers showed that I missed the grammatical issue. But they didn't suggest a solution to the problem I was presenting. I know that this answer does not technically suggest how to link css variables with scss variables.  at least it show how to avoid problem . that is why i accept this answer. 
I feel sad that no technical solution has been found.

Comment: Read the first line of the body, Robby. StackOverflow is *very* technical about this stuff, and I was merely conforming to that paradigm. Enjoy your victory lap. lol

Comment: @KimMinJae No technical solution is presented because of the fact that SASS variables are a compile-time construct. They can not be manipulated at runtime using JavaScript because they no longer exist at runtime, having been compiled into regular CSS. The same goes for all values based on SASS variables (e.g. results of calls to `transperentize()`). This is explained in greater detail in the [SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables).

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen Wow!! You are right!! it was impossible! why i didn't realize it !!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring the `: root` variable first, makes the code like this one.

Your code flow is not right. It may gonna help you. You should study this [article](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars)

```
$primary-color: #4c5b73;

: root{
   --primary-color: #{$primary-color};
}

.my-component {
   background-color: transparentize($primary-color, 0.85);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know,  but in order to do what i am trying to do.   I'm still struggling.   
Oh and I uploaded a code fan   if you don't mind plz try it

Comment: The problem of that approach is that it compiles the CSS for `.my-component` to `background-color: rgba(76, 91, 115, 0.15);`. Changing the value of the `primary-color` CSS variable through JavaScript will have not impact on the CSS for `.my-component`.

Answer (score -2):

You would use `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue`

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725725/access-css-variable-from-javascript) should get you what you need. :)

Comment: Are you saying if declare a variable with scss, it is converted to a css variable after compilation? 
I'm not just trying to do dynamic conversion.

Comment: CSS actually has variables (custom properties is what they are technically) now. ~95% coverage.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables