# HTML/CSS/Javascript: Get value of "main-variable" from my wrapper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, document

I have a wrapper like this (simple code):

```
<div class="wrapper" style="--main-color: #123456;">
...
</div>
```

I use the "--main-color" to change colors of different things (background, markers, etc.) a little bit easier or however to say.
Works perfectly fine in css with this:

```
.classname {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Now, what I want to with this too:
I have 4 different images, but only one should be shown (depends on which color is specified)

E.G.

```
#ff0000 --> <img.... src(red-img.png).../>
#00ff00 --> <img.... src(green-img.png).../>
```

I am trying it already with javascript, but I absolutely dont know how to get the value of my attribute "--main-color".

One thing i tried, that ofc didnt work:

```
let color = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue("--main-color");
```

Hope someone can help me with this..

Comment: You're on the right track with `getPropertyValue`, but you'll need to compute the styles first. Check out this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725782/1248133

Comment: Thank you! Didnt believe I was on the right way with that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
getComputedStyle(wrapper).getPropertyValue("--main-color");
```